# Parse SVG to Raphael Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Alright so I know some people have already asked this. However those questions are about two years old and I checked out the links to libs that they were suggesting and none of them work for what I need. I have googled this extensively trying to get some help on it as well and have found some good stuff but still none that do what I need them to do.

I am currently using [this plugin](https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic). This works great other than the fact that it does not support svg objects such as rect or circle that contain image fills. I received a nice lecture on how you should not be using images in SVG. I know. If someone could help me figure out how to get this plugin to work with image fills or possibly point me in the direction of one that does that would be great. If not well, thanks anyways.